# how to bind Checkbox with arraylist?

Tags: .net, vb.net

i want to bind arraylist into Checkbox which dynamically created.

what i want to do is  i check Checkbox 'testing' and check Checkbox 'testing2'

then iterate checked checkbox and open url each binded value

'www.yahoo.com'and 'www.msn.com'

following is what i done already .
thanks so much

```
    Dim data As String() = New String() {"testing : www.yahoo.com", "testing2 : www.msn.com"}
    Dim offset = 100
    Dim checkBox
    For Each cur In data
        checkBox = New CheckBox()
        Controls.Add(checkBox)
        checkBox.Location = New Point(450, offset)
        checkBox.Text = cur
        checkBox.Checked = False
        checkBox.Size = New Size(10, 20)
        offset = offset + 20
    Next
```

Comment: To do something like that, you need to use a dictionary where each key is an item in the checkbox and the value,  the URL.

Comment: would you give me some more details? like some sample? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using checkbox.tag property? Its an object oriented so you can put string in there and then use it later